# Download Office365 onenote file

Tags: sharepoint, office365, ms-office, onenote

I'm not able to export Office365 OneNote files from the Onenote site, I didn't find any option to export the file.

Please help to export the Onenote file and import it into another environment.

Comment: You could just go over to the site where the one note is located and just download the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Notebook files exist in the Site Assets folder (see Site Contents) of the SharePoint site. You should be able to copy the file from there to another environment. If you cannot do that you may need to ask your site admin to do it for you.